# "dynamic" url templatetag in Django

Tags: django, django-templates

Whether it is possible to use variable in "url" templatetag, ie:

```
{% url object.add %}
```

where:

```
object.add = 'myapp.view.function'
```

Any sugestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You will need to [write your own template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags) that invokes `reverse()`.